# RSpec response.body is still empty even with config.render_views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

In my spec_helper.rb file I have specifically set it to config.render_views but the response.body I get back is still empty. Here is my basic spec

```
describe  "#index" do
    it "should list all rooms" do
      get 'index'
      stub(Person).all
    end

    it "responds with 200 response code" do
      response.should be_ok
    end

    it "renders the index template" do
      pp response.body
      response.should render_template("people/index")
    end

  end
```

Is there anything else that could have shorted this behavior? It's fine when I go through the browser. I am on Rspec 2.5.0

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried having `render_views` in your controller spec file? That works for me.

Another thing I noticed is that you only access the index page once in your test cases - the first one to be precise. The rest will return empty html content because there is no response.

This is how I will implement it. But if you already have `config.render_views` in the *spec_helper.rb* file and that works, you can do without the `render_views` in the controller spec.

```
describe MyController
    render_views

    before :each do
        get :index
    end

    describe  "#index" do
        it "should list all rooms" do
            stub(Person).all
        end

        it "responds with 200 response code" do
            response.should be_ok
        end

        it "renders the index template" do
            pp response.body
            response.should render_template("people/index")
        end
    end
end
```

EDIT:
The subtle change here is the `before` blobk in which I call `get :index` for every `it` block.

Comment: Did you fix your code by including `get :index` into every `it` block?

Comment: You certainly need `get :index` in every test, or better, in a `before` as @Yasky has shown.  Your `stub` is also doing nothing in the test it's in.  Stubbing after the `get` is going to have no effect.  You're also not returning anything from the stub.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue.

The solution was to specify the format of the request.

For example:

`get :some_action, some_param: 12121, format: 'json'`

Answer (score 0):

This was changed from RSpec 1 to RSpec 2. View specs now use `rendered` instead of `response`:

`rendered.should =~ /some text/`

More info in the [release notes on github](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails).

Comment: I'm not in a view spec, it's a controller spec and the docs still show dealing with a response in this fashion