# railstutorial.org - rspec failed but in browser everything is OK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am trying to follow [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec%3arequiring_signed_in_users) and I have a failed rspec but in browser the app  works as needed. That is when I am signed in (in browser) and go to "http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit" this page opens. All previous rspecs from the tutorial are passed.

I am using Rails '3.1.0.rc4' and working in Windows.

The spec which fails (from users_controller_spec.rb):

```rb
describe "GET 'edit" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
      test_sign_in(@user)
    end

    it "should be successful" do
      get :edit, :id => @user
      response.should be_success
    end
end
```

code of test_sign_in from spec_helper.rb:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|  
  config.mock_with :rspec

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  def test_sign_in(user)
    controller.sign_in(user)
  end
end
```

code of factories.rb

```rb
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name "Mikhail"
  user.email "mikleb@yandex.ru"
  user.password "123456789a"
  user.password_confirmation "123456789a"
end
```

text from console:

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET 'edit should be successful
     Failure/Error: response.should be_success
       expected success? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:111:in `block (3 levels) in <
top (required)>'
```

UPD: After "get :edit, :id => @user" user is not signed in. But as I wrote in browser everything works as needed. How is that possible?

here is SessionHelper which is included in ApplicationControlelr:

```rb
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def sign_out
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @curent_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
  end

  def deny_access
    redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in to access this page."
  end

  private
    def user_from_remember_token
      User.authenticate_with_salt(*remember_token)
    end

    def remember_token
      cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil, nil]
    end
end
```

Comment: Please post the code for the factory from spec/factories
Should be user_factory.rb

Comment: I have spec/factories.rb instead of user_factory.rb. (I have posted the code)

Comment: The part that stands out as confusing is that you are assigning @user to :id...wouldn't id be an integer or some kind of number? or at worst, a string of some sort, but definitely not a User object.

Comment: @jaydel It has been the case for a while (at least since 2.3.x) that in generating routes you can assign either an object or its actual id to most id fields (for example, in the old `url_for` style instead of named route helpers), so that is likely not the issue (we still do things like `user_path(@user)` when user_path only uses the id).

Comment: I didn't know that. Good information, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you dumped `response.body` to see what Rspec thinks it's seeing? You may (I forget if this is still necessary) need to enable `render_views` as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875423/rspec-response-body-is-still-empty-even-with-config-render-views)).

Is it possible the user is not really logged in and thus the site is redirecting from edit to the sign-in page or something similar?

Another caveat, I am pretty sure rspec only returns true for `be_success` if the HTTP code is a 2xx code (200 ok, 201 created, etc). So if your controller is redirecting (302, 304, etc) then rspec will not consider the request to have "been successful."

Try dropping in a `puts response.body` before your assertion, it may help you narrow down your problem.

Comment: response.body is "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"http://test.host/signin\">red
irected</a>.</body></html>". It looks like user not really signed in. But in browser it is works fine.